# Obtener registros entre dos DATETIME en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Necesito obtener los registros disponibles entre dos columnas `DATETIME` en SQL Server, de forma que una columna es el inicio y otra el final.
Es decir, al momento de hacer una consulta basada en ambos valores, obtener los datos que se encuentren en el rango de los DATETIME, o que afecten una parte de ese intervalo.
Por ejemplo, hacer una consulta que con un inicio `'2016-12-07 07:30'` y final `'2016-12-08 10:45'`. Básicamente necesito que la consulta retorne registros que cumplan los siguientes casos:

- Registros que empiecen y finalicen dentro del intervalo.
- Registros que empiecen antes del inicio del intervalo pero finalicen dentro del
  mismo.
- Registros que empiecen después del inicio del intervalo y que
  terminen después del final del intervalo.
- Registros que empiecen antes del inicio del intervalo, y finalicen
  después del final del intervalo.

Básicamente, el objetivo son los registros que estén contenidos al menos, parcialmente o completamente.
He utilizado la siguiente consulta, pero no funciona en todos los casos:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLA WHERE (VALOR_INICIO BETWEEN INICIO AND FINAL)
OR (VALOR_FINAL BETWEEN INICIO AND FINAL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asumiendo que `inicio` y `final` se refieren a las columnas en tu tabla, y `valor_inicio` y `valor_final` se refieren a los parámetros que definen el intervalo que buscas, entonces se pueden condensar todos tus requisitos con la sentencia siguiente:

```
-- @valor_inicio = '2016-12-07 07:30'
-- @valor_final  = '2016-12-08 10:45'
select *
  from tabla t
 where (@valor_inicio >= t.inicio or @valor_final >= t.inicio)
   and (@valor_inicio <= t.final or @valor_final <= t.final)
```

**Edición**

Me acabo de dar cuenta que la consulta se puede simplificar aún más. La siguiente consulta es suficiente:

```
select *
  from tabla t
 where @valor_final >= t.inicio
   and @valor_inicio <= t.final
```

Comment: @miguel: Se me acaba de ocurrir que la consulta se puede simplificar aún más. Edité la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que necesitas el siguiente script:

```
USE basededatos

declare @startDate datetime
set @startDate = '2016-11-01 09:10'

declare @endDate datetime
set @endDate = '2016-11-01 18:00'

-- Registros que empiecen y finalicen dentro del intervalo.
select * from TABLA where (COL_INICIO between @startDate and @endDate) 
AND (COL_FINAL between @startDate and @endDate)

-- Registros que empiecen antes del inicio del intervalo pero finalicen dentro del mismo.
select * from TABLA where COL_INICIO < @startDate and 
(COL_FINAL between @startDate and @endDate)

--Registros que empiecen después del inicio del intervalo y que terminen después del final del intervalo.
select * from TABLA where COL_INICIO > @startDate and 
(COL_FINAL > @endDate)

-- Registros que empiecen antes del inicio del intervalo, y finalicen
después del final del intervalo.
select * from TABLA where COL_INICIO < @startDate and 
(COL_FINAL > @endDate)
```

Te puede servir declarar(DECLARE) variables para que las fechas no las escribas en cada SELECT (si es un solo script), para hacer el filtrado de fechas en SQL Server te sirven los operadores de comparación como: "<", ">", "<=", ">="

Operadores de comparación: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms188074(v=sql.120).aspx

Comment: Funcionan de maravillas. A propósito, lo estoy ejecutando a través de un procedimiento almacenado que recibe la dos variables. ¿Existe alguna forma de fusionar todo en un solo resultado? No importa que existan varios `SELECT`, lo que me interesa es que cuando llame ese procedimiento almacenado, retorne los registros obtenidos de todos los casos. Gracias.

Comment: Si insertas los 4 'SELECT' en tu procedimiento almacenado este te regresará 4 tablas, si quieres el resultado de todos los SELECT en una tabla tienes que poner un OR en cada filtro del WHERE, por ejemplo

Comment: ... `where (COL_INICIO between @startDate and @endDate) 
AND (COL_FINAL between @startDate and @endDate) OR COL_INICIO < @startDate and 
(COL_FINAL between @startDate and @endDate)`